# How should alias in command substitution behave?

Tags: shell, alias, posix, command-substitution, syntax

I tested a few scripts with different shells, and the results differ.

```
# test 1
foo(){ echo $(al);}
alias al='echo 123'
foo

# test 2
alias al='echo 123'
foo(){ echo $(al);}
alias al='echo abc'
foo

# test 3
alias foo='echo $('
echo $(foo echo '123'))

# test 4
alias foo='echo $('
echo "$(foo echo '123'))"

# test 5
alias bar='echo 123)'
echo $(bar
```

|  | bash 5.1.16 (with --posix) | ksh 2020.0.0 | zsh 5.9 | dash 0.5.12 | yash 2.53 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test 1 | 123 | 123 | 123 | al: not found | no such command `al` |
| test 2 | abc | abc | abc | 123 | 123 |
| test 3 | unexpected token `)` | `)` unexpected | 123 | 123 | 123 |
| test 4 | 123 | 123 | 123 | 123 | 123 |
| test 5 | unexpected EOF | `(` unmatched | command not found: barecho | 123 | 123 |

So basically bash and ksh make lazy alias substitution, and dash and yash make eager alias substitution. The behaviour of zsh is kind of difficult to explain, espicially in case 5, when it tries to find command `barecho`.

Test 4 is the only case that all shells argee. This is confusing,because [POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) [2.2.3 Double-Quotes](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_03) says:

> The input characters within the quoted string that are also enclosed between "$(" and the matching ')' shall not be affected by the double-quotes, but rather shall define that command whose output replaces the "$(...)" when the word is expanded. The tokenizing rules in Token Recognition, not including the alias substitutions in Alias Substitution, shall be applied recursively to find the matching ')'.

The standard says the shell should not take alias substitution when trying to find the matching parentheses in command substitution within double quotes. But all shells use alias substitution within double quotes, while some does not if there were not double quotes.

The question is: are some shells wrong in some case, or are they simply different? i.e. Is there some rule saying what the correct behaviour should be in such cases?